# UITableView Multiple Section Conflicts When Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, sdwebimage

there is a weird issue about `UITableView`. I have 3 data source it means 3 section in `UITableView`. When I scroll the `UITableView`, button and images are conflicting. Button is disappearing, images are becoming deformed.

Here my `cellForRowAt` method.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventnetworkingcell", for: indexPath) as! EventNetworkCell

        var name: String = ""
        var job: String = ""
        var company: String = ""
        var img: Int?

        cell.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 45
        cell.userImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            name = self.matchmaking[indexPath.row].name
            job = self.matchmaking[indexPath.row].job
            company = self.matchmaking[indexPath.row].company
            img = self.matchmaking[indexPath.row].image


        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {

            name = self.networkInEvent[indexPath.row].name
            job = self.networkInEvent[indexPath.row].job
            company = self.networkInEvent[indexPath.row].company
            img = self.networkInEvent[indexPath.row].image

            cell.addButtonOutlet.alpha = 0
        }
        else {

            name = self.allAttendees[indexPath.row].name
            job = self.allAttendees[indexPath.row].job
            company = self.allAttendees[indexPath.row].company
            img = self.allAttendees[indexPath.row].image


        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = name
        cell.jobLabel.text = job
        cell.companyLabel.text = company

        if let imgid = img {
            let url = MTApi.url(for: imgid, size: .normal)
            cell.userImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: [], completed: nil)
        }
}
        cell.addButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: 
  #selector(self.addNetwork(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell

    }
```

When I remove the `cell.addButtonOutlet.alpha = 0` line, buttons aren't disappearing.

And there is a video which shows the issue:

[Video](https://streamable.com/x4tdp)

Comment: first of all set     cell.addButtonOutlet.alpha = indexPath.row

Comment: secondly when wirttting any if condition in CellForRowAt indexpath always provide else condition too otherwise new cell will user reference of old cell and may show UI for previous cells :)

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue with cells reusing.

Basically, what's happening, is that the tableView creates only enough cells as much as there are visible on the screen, and once a cell gets scrolled out of view, it gets reused for another item in your dataSource.

The reason for buttons seemingly disappearing is that that you've already removed the button previously, but now, when reusing haven't told the cell to show the button again.

Fixing this is easy, just add:

```
cell.addButtonOutlet.alpha = 0
```

to your sections 0 and 2 (else block).

Same thing with images, the previous image is retained unless you tell the cell to remove the image if needed, so just add this:

```
if let imgid = img {
    let url = MTApi.url(for: imgid, size: .normal)
    cell.userImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: [], completed: nil)
} else {
    cell.userImageView.image = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var name: String = ""
    var job: String = ""
    var company: String = ""
    var img: Int?

    cell.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 45
    cell.userImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.addButtonOutlet.alpha = 1   // add more
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
     ........
```

and you should research about UITableviewCell reuse.